# Condition FOR/WHILE in M function - Paginate API in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m, language-model

I created this API paginated below. It roughly works, but in the OFFSET property, I need to stipulate instead of the number of the next sequence number of the record, for example, for the second page, the number 251, the next record of the second page, and so on.

- My record limit per page is 250
- The field `totalItems` returned the total of records, for example: 4500
- I divide the total number of records by the total number of records per page, to get to know how many pages my API has: `pageRange = {0..Number.RoundUp(totalItems / 250)}`
- When going to the second page, what happens in the API below, is that the records of the second page are coming repeated, because I should instead use the number 1 (referring to the second page), pass the number 251, and then, when doing the loop again, pass the number 501, until finishing the whole sequence (this parameter in the API is: `offset=`).

I need alter this line to include the FOR/WHILE for the item "ufnCallAPI(_)" of *`pages = List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(_)),`*

For example, the item above:

```
List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(_)),
List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(250)),
List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(500)),
List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(750)),
```

up to the total number *`totalItems`*

and include a FOR/WHILE to modified my API to not pass the number of the next page, but the number of the beginning of the list of the next item start (offset).

Thanks very much!

My code:

```
     let
        ufnCallAPI = (offSet) =>
            let
                query = Web.Contents("https://api.vhsys.com/v2/pedidos?offset=" & Number.ToText(offSet)  &  "&limit=250", 
                [Headers=[#"access-token"="OCKNYbAMaDgLBZBSQPCOGPWOXGSbdO", #"secret-access-token"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]]),
                result = Json.Document(query)
            in
                result,
    
            tmpResult = ufnCallAPI(1),
    
            auxTotal1 = Record.ToTable(tmpResult),
            Value = auxTotal1{2}[Value],
            auxTotal2 = Value[total],
            totalItems = auxTotal2 -1,
            pageRange = {0..Number.RoundUp(totalItems / 250)},
    
            pages =List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(_)),
            pages2 = Table.FromList(pages, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
            pages3 = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(pages2, "Column1", {"code", "status", "paging", "data"}, {"Column1.code", "Column1.status", "Column1.paging", "Column1.data"}),
            pages4 = Table.ExpandListColumn(pages3, "Column1.data"),
            pages5 = Table.RemoveColumns(pages4,{"Column1.code", "Column1.status", "Column1.paging"}),
            data = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(pages5, "Column1.data", {"id_ped", "id_pedido", "id_cliente", "nome_cliente", "id_local_retirada", "id_local_cobranca", "vendedor_pedido", "vendedor_pedido_id", "listapreco_produtos", "valor_total_produtos", "desconto_pedido", "desconto_pedido_porc", "peso_total_nota", "peso_total_nota_liq", "frete_pedido", "valor_total_nota", "valor_baseICMS", "valor_ICMS", "valor_baseST", "valor_ST", "valor_IPI", "condicao_pagamento_id", "condicao_pagamento", "frete_por_pedido", "transportadora_pedido", "id_transportadora", "data_pedido", "prazo_entrega", "referencia_pedido", "obs_pedido", "obs_interno_pedido", "status_pedido", "contas_pedido", "comissao_pedido", "estoque_pedido", "ordemc_emitido", "data_cad_pedido", "data_mod_pedido", "id_aplicativo", "id_pedido_aplicativo", "lixeira"}, {"id_ped", "id_pedido", "id_cliente", "nome_cliente", "id_local_retirada", "id_local_cobranca", "vendedor_pedido", "vendedor_pedido_id", "listapreco_produtos", "valor_total_produtos", "desconto_pedido", "desconto_pedido_porc", "peso_total_nota", "peso_total_nota_liq", "frete_pedido", "valor_total_nota", "valor_baseICMS", "valor_ICMS", "valor_baseST", "valor_ST", "valor_IPI", "condicao_pagamento_id", "condicao_pagamento", "frete_por_pedido", "transportadora_pedido", "id_transportadora", "data_pedido", "prazo_entrega", "referencia_pedido", "obs_pedido", "obs_interno_pedido", "status_pedido", "contas_pedido", "comissao_pedido", "estoque_pedido", "ordemc_emitido", "data_cad_pedido", "data_mod_pedido", "id_aplicativo", "id_pedido_aplicativo", "lixeira"}),
        #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(data,{{"id_ped", type text}, {"id_pedido", Int64.Type}, {"nome_cliente", type text}, {"valor_total_produtos", type text}}),
        #"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Tipo Alterado",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"valor_total_produtos"}),
        #"Tipo Alterado1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Valor Substituído",{{"valor_total_produtos", Currency.Type}}),
        #"Valor Substituído1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Tipo Alterado1",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"desconto_pedido", "desconto_pedido_porc", "peso_total_nota", "peso_total_nota_liq", "frete_pedido", "valor_total_nota", "valor_baseICMS", "valor_ICMS", "valor_baseST", "valor_ST", "valor_IPI"}),
        #"Tipo Alterado2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Valor Substituído1",{{"desconto_pedido", Currency.Type}, {"desconto_pedido_porc", Currency.Type}, {"peso_total_nota", Currency.Type}, {"peso_total_nota_liq", Currency.Type}, {"frete_pedido", Currency.Type}, {"valor_total_nota", type text}, {"valor_baseICMS", Currency.Type}, {"valor_ICMS", Currency.Type}, {"valor_baseST", Currency.Type}, {"valor_ST", Currency.Type}, {"valor_IPI", Currency.Type}, {"prazo_entrega", type text}, {"data_pedido", type date}}),
        #"Colunas Removidas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Tipo Alterado2",{"id_aplicativo", "id_pedido_aplicativo", "lixeira"}),
        #"Tipo Alterado3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Colunas Removidas",{{"valor_total_nota", type text}}),
        #"Valor Substituído2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Tipo Alterado3",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"valor_total_nota"}),
    #"Tipo Alterado4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Valor Substituído2",{{"valor_total_nota", Currency.Type}})
    
    in
    #"Tipo Alterado4"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly of web scraping then I would suggest you don't need to apply for/while loop.

Please, review the below link which might help your issue.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0bSddoCmss

https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/scrape-data-multiple-web-pages-power-query

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved using the post: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-M-function-in-Paginate-API/m-p/1091882